# Makefile for building an rpm works locally, but not in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, makefile, package, rpm

I have a makefile for building debian and rpm packages. I have two Jenkins environments, one for Ubuntu and one for CentOS. The debian package works no problem, and the rpm make command works on my machine, but not on Jenkins. Jenkins returns the following error:

`cp: cannot stat /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/myfile.file': No such file or directory`

`error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.mII8KL (%install)`

I was getting similar errors when developing the package but eventually figured everything out, and all was good. I think the problem may lie with `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT`, `%{buildroot}`, or `_topdir` options. Nothing I have tried has led me anywhere however.

Here is my (modified) Makefile:

```
# a list of tools we depend on and must install if they're missing
DEBTOOLS=/usr/bin/debuild-pbuilder
RPMTOOLS=/usr/bin/rpmbuild

# convenience target for "make deb"
deb: my-package_1.0_all.deb

# convenience target for "make rpm".  
rpm: my-package-1.0-Public.x86_64.rpm

# the target package (on Ubuntu at least)
my-package_1.0_all.deb: $(DEBTOOLS)
    cd my-package; debuild-pbuilder -us -uc

my-package-1.0-Public.x86_64.rpm: $(RPMTOOLS)
    cd rpmbuild; rpmbuild -bb SPECS/my-package.spec

/usr/bin/debuild-pbuilder:
    apt-get -y install pbuilder

/usr/bin/rpmbuild:
    yum -y install rpm-build
```

This is my spec file:

```
Summary: My Package
Name: my-package
Version: 1.0
Release: Public
Group: Applications/System
License: Public
Requires: external-package
Source1: myfile.file

%description
blah blah

%files
%config /etc/myfile.file

%install
mkdir -p $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/etc/
cp %{SOURCE1} %{buildroot}/etc/myfile.file

%post
ln -sf /etc/myfile.file /etc/external-package.conf
```

Comment: What did you do locally to fix this problem? What environment of rpm macros/defines/etc. does the jenkins build run under? That error means your sources aren't where rpm believes they should be. Are they there? If not where are they? How are you telling rpm where they actually are?

Comment: to fix the original problem i changed my `Makefile`. originally I was calling `rpmbuild -D '_topdir .' -bb SPECS/myspec.spec` to build relative to the directory where I pulled my code from git (as this is what Jenkins is doing). I removed the change to the `_topdir` variable to get the build to work.

Comment: And where does `myfile.file` live on the jenkins build machine? Not in `/root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/myfile.file` clearly.

Comment: the problem seems to be that the files aren't being moved to the buildroot when called. the local installation does this just fine. if if echo those variables i get similar paths. I have no idea how I could do anything about this because the buildroot handles its own thing i can only tell it what directory to use.

Comment: I was using the `%{_topdir} variable incorrectly. Problem solved.

Comment: If you figured out your problem (and it is something that might be useful for someone else) then you should add an answer to the question and accept it. If that isn't the case then you should probably delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in fact that the file wasn't being found (obviously). For me this had a lot to do with the confusing nature of building rpm files. When the `make` command is executed, and the `rpmbuild` command is called, I needed to be able to specify the directory. When reading the documentation, it was stated you could use `rpmbuild -D '_topdir .' -bb path/to/spec.spec` to set the _topdir variable to the local directory you call from. This made sense as `.` represents this in linux.

However the actual call needs to be

```
rpmbuild -D "_topdir `pwd`" -bb path/to/spec.spec
```

This doesn't look all that different except it is crucial to use double-quotes. Using this command will run the build within the directory you call it from. After this `rpmbuild` will copy and handle the files for you as it should (which is confusing in itself).